# Why isn't JSZip compressing string files like desktop archivators do?

Tags: javascript, zip, jszip

I have a large JS object which I want to save to local storage. I want to save it compressed so I do the following:

```
JSON.stringify(article).length which gives me 168478
```

Now if I put the output of the above into .txt file in Windows, its size is 169246, which is close to the  output for `JSON.stringify`. Now I want to compress the file. I compressed the desktop version using WinRAR to `.zip` format and it gave the output of `11284`, which is substantial compression. Now I try the same with JSZip:

```
zip.file('article1', JSON.stringify(article));
var content = zip.generate({type : "string"});
```

And if I check zipped content size `content.length` I get 176296, which is even bigger than the original stringified object. So am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that strings in javascript are encoded in UTF-16. So a 10MB ascii text file will take 20MB of memory.

Comment: The text is not restricted to ASCII charactares only, it contains characters from languages that require 16MB.

Comment: @Maximus "not ASCII characters only" maybe is the reason not the twice of the original package? And the encoding of JS perhaps is the cause of the larger package you get.

Comment: The text is identical on windows and in browser, so on windows it also takes 16 byte per character.